# combineLatest emits values 2 times with Firestore for only 1 value added

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, ionic4

**Update 4:** No Cloud function usage here. Only `createMessage()` method.

**Update 3:** Please see the issue as Gif. Click it to see the big screen.

[image]

**Update 2:** Just a simple subscription where it emits value 2 times. Any clue?

```
 this.chatSubscription = messagesPerChatGroup$.subscribe(async (messages, 
                        ) => {

                 //code

                });
```

**Update: 1** This only still fires 2 times. Any clue?

```
 this.chatSubscription = combineLatest([messagesPerChatGroup$, 
                      ]).subscribe(async ([messages, 
                    ]) => {

             //code

            });
```

**Original**
I have this subscription and it is working fine for the first time.

```
const messagesPerChatGroup$: Observable<ChatMessageModel[]> = 
    this.chatService.getMessagesPerChatGroup(this.groupId);

const userActionsPerChatGroup$: Observable<UserActionModel[]> = 
    this.chatService.getUserActionsPerChatGroup(this.groupId);

const memberIdsPerChatGroup$: Observable<MessageGroupMemberModel> = 
    this.chatService.getMemberIdsPerChatGroup(this.groupId);

this.chatSubscription = combineLatest([
    messagesPerChatGroup$, 
    userActionsPerChatGroup$,
    memberIdsPerChatGroup$
]).subscribe(async ([messages, actions, memberIds]) => {
    //code             
});
```

service

```
getMessagesPerChatGroup(chatGroupId: string): Observable<ChatMessageModel[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<ChatMessageModel>(`messageGroups/${chatGroupId}/messages`).valueChanges();
}
```

When I add an item to the above collection `this.chatSubscription` emits values 2 times. Why is that and what is the solution here?
i.e.  `messageGroups/${chatGroupId}/messages`

*This is how I add records.*

```
async createMessage(chatGroupId: string, message: ChatMessageModel, userIdToken: string): Promise<void> {
    const messageDocId: string = this.afs.createId();
    await this.afs.doc<ChatMessageModel>(`messageGroups/${chatGroupId}/messages/${messageDocId}`).set({
        senderId: message.senderId,
        text: message.text,
        timeSent: message.timeSent,
        timeReceivedByServer: message.timeReceivedByServer,
        notificationSent: message.notificationSent,
    });
}
```

*Send button method:*

```
  send(): void {
    const message: ChatMessageModel = {
      senderId: this.uid,
      text: this.form.value.text,
      timeSent: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(Date.now())),
      timeReceivedByServer: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      notificationSent: false,
    };
    this.chatService.createMessage(this.groupId, message, this.userIdToken);
    this.form.reset();
  }
```

Comment: @AndrewAllen Still same behavior. Any clue?

Comment: @AndrewAllen `distinctUntilChanged()` would probably not be relevant since those are objects, and `distinctUntilChanged()` doesn't check for deep-equality between 2 `object`s rather checks for them having the same reference, or the same value in case of `number`s, `boolean`s and `string`s, etc....

Comment: Another wild guess here, do you run any cloud functions that gets triggered when you add a message to the collection? If that function updated any of your documents, it could trigger another emit

Comment: @Sampath did you check if a message is truly being added only once, meaning `createMessage()` (or whichever other function inserts a document to that collection) is called only once?

Comment: @AmitB. Yes, it adds only 1 record to the Firestore. Any clue?

Comment: You could always pass in a function to distintuntilchanged to check for equality [see example 3](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged). Also a quicker debugging step is to add `.pipe(tap(console.log))` to your observables to see what’s firing and it’s value. I’m guessing something *must* be causing valuechanges to fire twice...perhaps createId does something that triggers valuechanges

Comment: @AndrewAllen I have commented out it (`this.afs.createId();`) and tried that. But still the same mysterious issue.

Comment: I’ll stop spamming with my guesses :) especially given my limited knowledge of firestore but as parting shots maybe [limiting events](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#component-example) and is createMessage definitely 100% called only once?

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes, please see the Update `Send button method:`

Comment: @SnorreDan No cloud function usage here. Only `createMessage()` method.

Comment: this how combineLatest works - emits value with latest from each source, meaning it would be triggered each time one of the sources emits value(they cannot emit at the same time). solution: take a look at creational observables like zip/forkJoin(try what better for you). Also, try not to use async/await with observable - you are transforming declarative-reactive approach to imperative.

Comment: to understand what is going on and what is your solution read this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom . Also, cannot provide a full solution because of lacking some stackblitz from your side for a quick start off

Comment: @Sampath any update?

Comment: @AndrewAllen I was not able to find out solution here. I just ignore 2nd fire withing the method to show correct data to the user. i.e. ugly hack